# VueJS/vuex application design question - how to initialize local data with getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, architecture, vuex

**Context:**

I have a reports application that contains a report editor. This Report Editor is used to edit the contents of the report, such as the title, the criteria for filtering the results, the time range of results, etc..

**The Problem:**

There is something wrong with the way I have used Vuex/Vuejs in my components I believe. My store contains getters for each aspect of this report editor. Like this:

```
const getters = {
    activeReportTitle: state => {
        return state.activeReport.title;
    },
    activeReportID: state => {
        return state.activeReport.id;
    },
    timeframe: state => {
        return state.activeReport.timeframe;
    },
    includePreviousData: state => {
        return state.activeReport.includePreviousData;
    },
    reportCriteria: state => {
        return state.activeReport.reportCriteria;
    },
    emailableList: state => {
        return state.activeReport.emailableList;
    },
    dataPoints: state => {
        return state.activeReport.configuration?.dataPoints;
    },
    ...
```

Each getter is used in a separate component. This component uses the getter only to initialize the local data, and uses actions to modify the state. The way I have done this is by adding a local data property and a watcher on the getter that changes the local data property. The component is using the local data property and that data property is sent to the action and the getter is updated.

ReportSearchCriteria.vue

```
...
 data() {
    return {
      localReportCriteria: [],
      currentCriteria: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    reportCriteria: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(val) {
        this.localReportCriteria = [...val];
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    ...reportStore.mapGetters(['reportCriteria'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...reportStore.mapActions(["updateReportCriteria"]),
    addSearchCriteria() {
      if (this.currentCriteria) {
        this.localReportCriteria.push(this.currentCriteria);
        this.updateReportCqriteria(this.localReportCriteria);
      }
        this.currentCriteria = "";
        this.$refs['reportCriteriaField'].reset();
    },
...
```

The hierarchy of the components is set up like this
Reports.Vue

- GraphEditor.vue
- ReportSearchCriteria.vue

Comment: Based on my understanding (or not) of your question, you don't need watchers.  You can set up computed properties that return the getters.  And you don't really need getters.  Example: ```computed: { activeReportTitle() { return this.$store.state.activeReport.title } }```.  The computed property will be used instead of local data.  Also, to update Vuex state, unless you are getting the new values from asynchrounous methods (API calls) you can use mutations instead of actions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what the problem is? Does the 'reportCriteria' not get updated when it's supposed to? How does the function 'updatedReportCriteria' look like? You use mutations to update a state in the store. Also, you have a typo when you're calling the action.